# SQLServer 2014 - have user access only one database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am new to sql server so need help with this... Though I have added a user and under user mapping I have only one database that user can access, from within my application I can see he can access :master,msdb and tempdb (as well as the database I have granted him the access to).Not only from my application but also using managment studio as well. How comes he can access these first three options (databases) ? How can I have him access only designated database and nothing else?

Comment: This is probably relevant: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2539091

Comment: I have the gust account enabled. I tested the issue with the supplied query on that page and everything seems ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logins with `CONNECT` privilege can also access databases with the `guest` user enabled.  The `master` and `tempdb` system databases require the `guest` user to be enabled for SQL Server to be functional.  Enabling the `guest` user in `msdb` is optional, but some applications may not operate correctly without it enabled.

Note that access to these system databases is not normally a security concern due to meta-data visibility restrictions.